# Is there an IDE for CSS with code validation?

Tags: css, ide

What's a good IDE for CSS that **makes validation** of the code as you type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Netbeans also has that and is free. And for what its worth there is also dreamweaver but I have no idea how good it is compared to more "serious" ide's.

Comment: Dreamweaver from what I've seen is perfect just for this, but it's too bulky and not feature-rich in other directions, and it's a commercial product. As of NetBeans, I've experienced UI lags when editing CSS. Each new character I entered triggered a recoloring of the syntax, which I could see happening (flickering).

Comment: and which version you would recommend? The php one? (for css, html and  possibly javascript)

Comment: @Tom well I can only recommend NetBeans since I do php and other dev and it covers it all for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) or [Visual Web Developer Express 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-Web-Developer)

Aptana is Eclipse-based, cross-platform, needs no installation, just JRE. Pretty neat, I use it. In CSS it even provides code completion for selectors (based on what you have in HTML). If a line is invalid an error sign appears next to it, hover your cursor and read what's wrong.

Visual Web Developer is harder for me because I spent too few hours CSSing in it. From what I've seen it does a pretty decent job, but I still prefer Aptana.

Comment: So something is wrong with my Aptana, becouse it is not showing errors in my CSS file... In the preferences window I found nothing about error messages..

Comment: umm, strange. While in Aptana, try opening the file with right click->Open with->Aptana CSS Editor. Maybe something's wrong with the file associations. I'll get back with a definite solution, because I configured my instance over 2 years ago and I don't remember much since then.

Comment: Ok, here's an older version, which I have, with built-in PHP and smarty support. Everything works great here. http://www.mediafire.com/file/dej0i0uujkg/Aptana%20Studio%20Andretti.7z If you can't make version 2.0 behave properly (they've changed their features), then try this.

Answer (score 1):

All of the [jetbrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/) IDE products (with the exception of the free CE edition) include a every good CSS editor.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Mac for any development then I would advise CSS Edit although I expect that is not the case.